# Track user experience/behavior in an app

Tags: android, tracking, behavior

To improve my app I want to see how users actually use it.
 I am not having user accounts, it is an open app. 
 I would like to analyze how long (in actual time) people look at a certain screen and when they go to a next one or close it.
 I know there is **Google Analytics for Apps**, but I don't know if they keep track of it **this detailed**? Maybe there is another handy service/code out there which I could use?

Anyone using this service or another and has some user experience he/she wants to share? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two more that I would like to mention apart from Analytics

1. [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)
   Though it is basically for crash-reports but you can also add your custom parameters. 
   If you wish to refer it you can visit this  [Link](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)
2. [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/)

Comment: Any experience with them? Is it correct that Acra is about handling error reports and not the actual user behavior?

Comment: You know analytics does keep track of how long a user stays on a specific screen/page and when they go to the next one just like you want right?

Comment: I did not know that, but that is indeed what I am searching for. However, there might be other things out there which are worth mentioning which do the same..

Comment: please see updated answer for more ref.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup